# accumulo init failed to connect to zookeeper

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, accumulo

when i initial the accumulo with the command: accumulo init, error appears, cannot connect to the zookeeper,however the zookeeper is running: INFO:zookeeper is localhost:2181

```
Thread "init" died null
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.accumulo.start.Main$1.run(Main.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to zookeeper (localhost:2181) within 2x zookeeper timeout period 30000
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.util.Initialize.main(Initialize.java:498)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to zookeeper (localhost:2181) within 2x zookeeper timeout period 30000
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession.connect(ZooSession.java:96)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooSession.getSession(ZooSession.java:146)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReader.getSession(ZooReader.java:36)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReaderWriter.getZooKeeper(ZooReaderWriter.java:53)
    at org.apache.accumulo.fate.zookeeper.ZooReader.exists(ZooReader.java:70)
    at `enter code here`org.apache.accumulo.server.util.Initialize.zookeeperAvailable(Initialize.java:197)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.util.Initialize.doInit(Initialize.java:122)
    at org.apache.accumulo.server.util.Initialize.main(Initialize.java:494)
    ... 6 more
```

Comment: Which OS are you running on? Can you `telnet` to `localhost:2181`?

Comment: Check that conf/accumulo-site.xml specifies the correct zookeepers.